# Graphics Device initialization failed for : d3d, sw on windows xp 32-bit using JDK 1.8.0u131 and NetBeans 8.2

Tags: java, javafx, windows-xp, 32-bit

Client use Windows xp 32-bit so I don't have other choices.
I've developed JavaFX application using JDK 1.8.0u131 and NetBeans 8.2 32-bit

I'm getting the following error:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:221)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:205)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
Java Result: 1
```

I've no choice to use upgraded versions of libraries to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the full stack trace, including all “Caused by:” sections.

Comment: This happens if your program has access to the JavaFX classes, but not the JavaFX native libraries.  Are you sure you’re running with Java 8?  How are you running your application, exactly?

Comment: In project property, compile time library `javafx.classpath.extension` is present.

Comment: A .jar file contains Java classes.  A *native library* is not Java;  it’s a .dll or .so or .dylib file, which usually contains code compiled in C or C++.  JavaFX requires a number of native libraries;  for instance, JavaFX for Linux includes `libprism_es2.so`.  If you are running a single .jar file using Java 8, you don’t have to worry about it, but if you have created something like an .exe file, it must include every native library required by JavaFX.

Comment: Yeah I got it it is not supported in windows xp. I think I need to switch back to swing even if project is completed. It's my mistake I checked only if Java is supported supported on XP and not JavaFX.

Comment: I'll check with old JDK which hava JavaFX 2.1 that support win xp. Otherwise need to switch back to swing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed `JDK7u4` and `NetBeans IDE 7.1` and problem is solved but I can't migrate my project cause I have used higher version of libraries to develop `JavaFX` application.

> Use `JDK-7u4` and `NetBeans IDE 7.1` for developing JavaFX on Windows XP.

Need to switch back to swing.